# FullScreen HTML5 API not present on facebook iFrame on some applications

Tags: html, fullscreen, facebook-iframe

i'm working on a facebook game app. We had lost hope about fullscreen, but recently (like three weeks ago), this bug report https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/436162913102704 was change to "fixed".

Super happy with that, we tried on our own app, but the fullscreen button did not work. And, by inspecting the iframe, we can see it does not have any "allowFullscreen" tag.
Nonetheless, the person who signal the bug in the first place said the fix did work. (And I was able to verify it). Then I asked him directly, and he hasn't used any trick in order to make it work.
So, any Idea everyone?